# Probability and game of snap

Tags: probability

If you are not familiar with the rules of snap they are as follows:
-Two players start with half of a shuffled deck
-Each player turns up the top card of their pile
-If they match, then the person first to say "snap" gets both face-up piles.
My question is what will be the probability that the players will turn over 4 cards (2 each) without a match? So i've had a go at it. If its all 52 cards then (50/52*48/50*46/48*44/46) But i think i'm wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: What needs to be matched, the number on the card or whether the cards belong to the same house.

Comment: The number on the card (could be different suits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I just tried. Flip the card off the first player's stack. The card off the second player's will not match this card with probability $\frac{48}{51}$. The second time you draw the card off the first player's stack, there are two disjoint possibilities, either the card was one of the same rank as the previous burned cards or it was not. Since there are two ranks that have been burned(they can't be the same otherwise we'd have a match), then there are 6 cards that are of the same rank that could be flipped for Card 3. When the card is of the same rank as the previous burned cards, player 2 can now only match this card with 2 of the remaining cards in the deck, i.e. he won't match with probability $\frac{47}{49}$. If the card isn't one of the previous burned cards, then he can match with 3 of the remaining cards, i.e. he won't match with probability $\frac{46}{49}$. Using the law of total probability. We have the total probability would then be $\frac{48}{51} \times [\frac{6}{50} \cdot \frac{47}{49} + \frac{44}{50}\cdot \frac{46}{49}]$

Comment: That is correct! I have a question though. At the beginning when we flip first player's stack, it becomes 51/52 right? Why is it when we flip the second players card it becomes 48/51, not 50/51? and where did you get 44/50 from?

Comment: @MarieAnne I am not sure what you mean by "it becomes 51/52". What I am doing here is a method called constructive counting. I count all the ways in which the first four cards can't match. It doesn't matter what the first card picked is(do you see why?) so the first player can choose any of the 52/52 cards. The second player is constrained in what cards he can pick however. Three of the cards match the first card and there are 51 cards total(the first card was removed). So 48/51 "work". Continue the logic as I did in my post. Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: I dont understand why you put 44/50 *46/49> I get that player one for the first card could be 52/52, for the second card by player 2, it can't be the same as player 1's rank and so 51-3=48, so 48/51 for the second card, for the 3rd card, i'm confused. I get the first part that as 2 different rank cards are gone, 6 remain of the same rank so if the third card is one of the 6 (6/50) then the fourth card by the second player would be 47/49. But for the second possibility, why can he match with 3 of the remaining cards? Where does the 44/50 come from and why is it 46/49 instead of 47/49?

Comment: @MarieAnne we finished the first two cards and by construction they didn't match. Let me for demonstration purposes say that card 1 was a jack and card 2 was a queen. Now we have two possibilities for card 3. Either the card will be a jack or a queen or it won't. Since there are six remaining jacks and queens in the deck and there are 50 cards remaining this happens with probability 6/50. The other possibility is that card 3 isn't a jack or a queen. This happens with probability 44/50 because six of the cards are jacks or queens and therefore 44 are not.

Comment: Now if I select a jack or queen then card 4 matches with probability 47/49. Since the jack(or queen) was burned in the first two cards there are only two remaining jacks in the deck, meaning for card 4 to NOT match we have to select 47 out of the remaining 49 cards. Now let's say I didn't select a jack or queen. Then there are 3 cards that can match with this card(see the difference? We have three matching possibilities rather than two like in the case with the card matching a previous card). Since three are matching this means that 46 aren't matching, I.e 46 of the 49 cards dont match

Comment: I got it! Thank you!!